# Is it possible to persist new Entities in a @Pre/PostPersist Listener?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I am trying to setup my hibernate application to persist a new `Notification` entity everytime an `Activity` Entity is created - at the moment, everything i have tried the `Notification` just fails to persist silently (no errors in the logs but sql is never executed).

Can anyone confirm that it is even possible to persist additional entities in the Hibernate pre/postPersist listeners?

I have read in the documentation:

> A callback method must not invoke EntityManager or Query methods!

But I have read several other discussion threads that seem to indicate that it is possible.

For reference, the two approaches I have attempted are:

1. `@PrePersist` method - setting a cascade.ALL relationship between `Activity` and `Notification`, and in the PrePersist method simply creating a new `Notification` and linking it to the `Activity` being created in a hope that the `Notification` would be persisted.
2. `@PostPersist` method - using `@Configurable` and a ListenerClass, wiring in a service and creating a new `Notification` entity and then explicitly calling the entityManger persist

Can someone confirm what I am trying is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have to persist `Notification` in `@PrePersist` or `@PostPersist` function? The following code should persist both entities:

```
@Entity
public class Activity implements Serializable {
   @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private Notification notification;
}

@Entity
public class Notification implements Serializable { }

@Stateless
public class MrBean implements MrBeanInterface {
   @PersistenceContext()
   private EntityManager em;

   public void persistActivity() {
      Activity act = new Activity();
      act.setNotification(new Notification());
      em.persist(act);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**: you can try creating the link inside the Activity's constructor like this:

```
@Entity
public class Activity implements Serializable {
   @OneToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST})
   private Notification notification;

   public Activity() {
      this.notification = new Notification();
   }
}

@Entity
public class Notification implements Serializable { }

@Stateless
public class MrBean implements MrBeanInterface {
   @PersistenceContext()
   private EntityManager em;

   public void persistActivity() {
      Activity act = new Activity();
      em.persist(act);
   }
}
```

One thing to note is that I think you cannot use `@PostPersist`. To be more precise, you must link `Notification` to `Activity` before persisting `Activity` in order for `cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}` to work.

Comment: Thanks - I need to add the Notification in the pre/postPersist method as i want to be sure that every time an Activity is created, a corresponding Notification is also created. If you consider Notification to be an audit object that needs to be guaranteed, with the first solution there is a risk that someone could call em.persist(act); anywhere else in the codebase (a batch/operational class or just anyother Service class) and unless they also add the Notification code then we dont get our audit.

The second solution is what i tried for my approach 1) in original post but is failing silently.

Comment: @rhinds I have just updated my answer. You can create the link in Activity's constructor.

Comment: thanks, i will try this - although it still seems like it would not be ideal as would still be open for editing before persisting. Seems like pre-persist should be the right place to do this sort of operation, for example, we previously used prePersist method to set the modified dates of all objects, and meant the modified date could never be manually changed or overriden

Comment: The problem with using the constructor is that Hibernate uses it to instantiate objects when they are loaded - and as the notification needs to be created with additional info it causes problems (re-creates new notifications whenever hibernate loads the Entities)

Comment: However, having been playing around with it the prePersist&Cascade approach is now working (seems like it may have not been working originally as Hibernate created the Notification table with a foreign key to itself that could never be satisfied and was just failing silently in prePersist) - so will accept this answer as it describes the same details I was using for the @PrePersist & Cascade setup I was using..

Comment: =) Can you update your question with how you made it work? I may run into the same problem some day ^^.

Answer (score 2):

You can persist additional entities in Hibernate event listeners (insert, update, flush, etc) with the [StatelessSession](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/batch.html#batch-statelesssession) interface. But I don't know if this is also possible with strict JPA only code (`EntityManagerFactory` and `EntityManager`).

Comment: Yes, it is implementation specific, but Hibernate and EclipseLink both have something analogous.

Comment: Thanks - is this appropriate for runtime persists? I notice the docs refer to it as a batch operation interface and doesnt use any first/second level caching..